# DRF - how to reverse a class based view in api_root

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

In Django REST Framework, I'm trying to add an API root to a views.py that has class based views.

**Error:**

```
$ http http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/

Error - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'SnippetListView' not found. 'SnippetList' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**backend/views.py**

```
from backend.models import *
from backend.serializers import *

from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse



@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'snippets': reverse('SnippetList')
        # 'snippets': reverse('SnippetListView')
        # 'snippets': reverse('snippet-list')
        # 'snippets': reverse('snippet_list')
    })


class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

**backend/urls.py**

```
from backend import views
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.api_root),
    path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
]
```

**Docs:**

> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#creating-an-endpoint-for-the-highlighted-snippets

Comment: by the doc you show should be `reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format)` did you try it?

Comment: @BearBrown yes. same error output based on the first string argument

Comment: Solved - I needed to name the url. It was way further down in the tutorial.
`path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to name the view url in order to use the reverse.

```
#urls.py
path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),

#views.py
'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format)
```

The tutorial did not originally give names to the urls of the class based views.

Comment: Thanks! you just saved my coding career. Was so stuck that was about to give up.